# C# Operator Overloading, rewriting string?

Tags: c#, string, operator-overloading, overloading, operator-keyword

I'm very fresh to C# 
Currently learning Operator overloading
i'm trying to do something like this:

```
string val = 500; (I can't implicitly)
```

and then

```
Number n1 = val;
```

I manages to get the `Number n1 = someintvalue`, for instance:

```
Number n1 = 500;
```

like this:

```
public struct Number
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public Number(int Val)
    {
        Value = Val;
    }
    public static implicit operator Number(int num)
    {
        return new Number(num);
    }
}
```

However, when trying to make Number n1 = val; (when val is a string)
I simply cant since the first line cant compile:

```
string val = 500;
```

and the following wont work:

```
public static implicit operator string(int A)
{
    return new string(A);
}
```

because of 1 error which i can not understand
1)User-defined conversion must convert to or from the enclosing type

by the way i get the idea of op overload
underthis specific case of: `return new Number(num);` 
I simply init the `ctor`
still need some more fundemental understanding
thx ahead!

Comment: Side note: do not use `struct` unless you understand the difference between it and `class`, and explicitly need a `struct`. Mutable structs can cause all sorts of problems that are usually unnecessary.

Comment: Plus, `string val = 500;` is poor practice.  If you want a string then _use a string_: `string val = "500";`  C# is a strongly-typed language and should be treated as such - adding multiple type conversion overloads erodes that type safety.

Answer (score 5):

I presume the function you quote is within the `Number` class.  You have added a conversion operator from an `int` to a `string` within that class, which is not legal.  You can only add operators that convert to or from the type they're defined in, such as:

```
public static implicit operator string(Number A)
{
    return new string(A.Value);
}
```

which will fail because `string` does not have a constructor that takes an `int`.  You *could* do:

```
public static implicit operator string(Number A)
{
    return A.ToString();
}
```

But the *standard* way to "convert" to a string is to overload the `ToString` method, which the compiler often calls automatically when a conversion to string is requested:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I get what you did here. However, I do not understand how to make the string val = 500; within the void Main

Comment: `500` is an integer, not a string.  There is no implicit conversion from `int` to `string`, so you need either `string val = "500";` or string `val = 500.ToString();`.  C# is a type-safe language.  Don't try to use it like JavaScript.